# postfix check user database to prevent forged address

Tags: mysql, email, postfix-mta, mail-server

We are facing problem with our mail servers. We have two servers for the mail system, one is POP only (Dovecot installed) and another one is SMTP (postfix, amavis, pyzor, razor installed and sending only). Both the servers install iredmail instance.  MX record in the SMTP one. We have a shared user database on both the servers and configure SASL authentication in the SMTP server. We already stop backscattering by implementing Header Check PCRE.

Now we facing forged address spam sending where user id is `something@mydomain.com` and our system can pass this mail. Please help me so I can configure a list of usernames (i.e. `hash:/etc/postfix/clean_sender`) or point to mysql database and if any mail incoming with a username does not match this list, it will discard immediately.

An example of the problems is [shown in this extract from our logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byb-DDPKkVcOMTZabnBJOTRxb1E/view?usp=sharing):

```
*** ENVELOPE RECORDS active/XXXXX ***
message_size:    49356      785           1         0           49356
message_arrival_time: XXXXX
create_time: XXXXX
content_filter: smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
named_attribute: log_ident= XXXXX
named_attribute: rewrite_context=remote
sender: u@ XXXXX.com
named_attribute: log_client_name= XXXXX
named_attribute: log_client_address= XXXXX
named_attribute: log_client_port=51472
named_attribute: log_message_origin= XXXXX
named_attribute: log_helo_name= XXXXX
named_attribute: log_protocol_name=ESMTP
named_attribute: client_name= XXXXX
named_attribute: reverse_client_name= XXXXX
named_attribute: client_address= XXXXX
named_attribute: client_port=51472
named_attribute: helo_name= XXXXX
named_attribute: protocol_name=ESMTP
named_attribute: client_address_type=2
named_attribute: dsn_orig_rcpt=rfc822;bob.baxter@charles-stanley.co.uk
original_recipient: 
recipient: bob.baxter@charles-stanley.co.uk
```

```
*** MESSAGE CONTENTS active/75C6734077E ***
Received: from ip245c164.banglalionwimax.com (XXXXX)
        by smtp. XXXXX.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id XXXXX
        for <bob.baxter@charles-stanley.co.uk>; XXXXX
Message-ID: <7521347.20150606135549@barretthead.com
Date: XXXXX
Subject: Wesley, use you personal coupon - nayfeith
From: "Harris" <fgbagrlidak@e-sil.com>
To: <bob.baxter@charles-stanley.co.uk>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Priority: 3
Precedence: bulk
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="O74xv3RG7hejSBa3"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is best to put all the information in the question to make it easier for the experts to give you an answer. I have reformatted your question to make it easier to answer. You may find that the site [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/) is better suited for your question - or may even have an answer to a similar question already.

Comment: @BrianTompsett This mail-server configuration question is *blatantly* off-topic. Just flag questions like this for closure immediately - do not give them a free bump on to the front page by editing them.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [reject_unlisted_recipient](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) restriction, or [smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient) option.